# Updates are not factored to the database using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

Following code doesn't update my database for the record found and when looking at Azure SQL Profiler I see only this update statement.

```
update [dbo].[Identities]
set @p = 0
where ([Id] = @0)
```

and the code:

```
using (var db = new context())
{
    var member = db.Identities.Include("Member").Include("Roles")
                   .FirstOrDefault(i => id.Value == i.nameidentifier && i.identityprovider == provider.Value);

    if (member != null)
    {
        member.LastLoggedIn = DateTime.UtcNow;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: db.SaveChanges() do return 1.

Comment: It looks like its only a problem with datetime.

Comment: Yes im using code first, and if it updated that one record i would be happy @marc_s.  set @p = 0 is not really a update. I found the solution, i had set the property to computed and therefor it do not work. I have changed it to none and marked it as optional and hope the default value on sql server kicks in if its not set.